# How to prove this things being a set using ZF axioms?

Tags: set-theory

I am reading Garlign's three volumes mathematical analysis, and I'm confused about a sentence in his book,which says that:

> Suppose that $A$ is a set.For each $a \in A$, we can form the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha \in a}\alpha$(which is easy to proof that it is a set).Using the seperation axiom, we can then construct a set $I$ whose elements are exactly these intersections, and can then form the set $\bigcup_{i \in I}i$.

I am confused about how can we use the seperation axiom to construct that $I$ to be a set. If we want to use seperation axiom, we should first find a universal set, and we can construct a new set from it. However, I have no idea about how to find this universal set.

Comment: Hint: all the $a$s live in $A$, so all the $\alpha$s will live in $\bigcup A$. The elements of $\bigcap_{\alpha \in a} \alpha$ are then all elements of $\alpha$ -- where will these live?

Comment: @aidangallagher4 Do you mean that I can use $P(\cup{A})$(here, $P$ means powerset) as the universe set?

Comment: @aidangallagher4 I don’t think it’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find a set $B$ such that $\bigcap a\in B$ for all $a\in A$, then all there is to do is to apply the axiom of separation on $B$. Consider $B=\mathcal{P}[\bigcup \bigcup A]$. Fix an $a\in A$, then

$$ a\subseteq \bigcup A \ \rightarrow \ \bigcup a\subseteq \bigcup \bigcup A \ \rightarrow \ \bigcap a \subseteq \bigcup a \subseteq \bigcup \bigcup A. $$

Therefore $\bigcap a\in \mathcal{P}[\bigcup \bigcup A]$ as needed. $\Box$

I use a different notation where $\bigcup A=\bigcup_{a\in A}a$ and et cetera

Answer (score 0):

It’s not completely correct, if $\varnothing\in A$, then $\bigcap_{x\in \varnothing} x$, does not exist(It would have to be the set of all sets). On the other hand if you know $\varnothing\not\in A$, then you can prove the given statement using the axiom of separation on $\bigcup_{x\in a} x$.
Note: If you *define* the intersection as a subset of a union then the first point is not a problem, and the statement is completely correct.

Comment: In this book, the author defines $\cap_{a \in A}a$ to be $\{x \in \cup_{a \in A}a : for all a \in A, x \in a \}$. So, I don't think that if $\emptyset \in A$ would contribute to a paradox.

Comment: @UESTCfresh See my edit.

Comment: I can't understand why we should use seperation axiom on $\bigcup_{x\in a} x$, it is not a super set of set $I$ that I want to construct. Maybe we can try $P(\bigcup(\bigcup_{a \in A}a))$?

Comment: Why can’t you understand that?

Comment: I can‘t see how can we use seperation axiom on the union you mentioned, it is not the superset of $I$.